# POSTed Json body requires surrounding quotes

Tags: asp.net, json, rest

I have a controller method declared like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public override IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string data)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

When testing with Advanced Rest Client, or Powershell, I find that my Json body must be surrounded by single quotes.  Example: instead of

```
{"name":"Elroy", "age":99}
```

I have to provide

```
'{"name":"Elroy", "age":99}'
```

If not in quotes, the my method receives an empty value for the "data" parm.

My ARC client DOES specify content-type="application/json"

That's not right, is it?  The outer quotes shouldn't be necessary, right?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct because JSON is transmitted as a string over the wire, not as an object graph. Hence the need for the quotes to denote that it is a string.

Comment: So I guess, to avoid the quoting requirement, I could take the parm off of the method declaration, and access the body by reading the request stream.

Comment: Clearly, it's possible to post json content without quoting it.  Even if unquoted, it comes in the request stream.  The problem is that .net mvc does not map it to a parameter of type string which is marked as [FromBody]  unless it is quoted.   Our solution was to create a new attribute [JsonStringFromBody] , subclassed from ParameterBindingAttribute, that we use in place of [FromBody].  The new attribute reads the stream from the request object and returns the body as a string, thus allowing the method mapping.   It seems like a mistake that [FromBody] doesn't do this.

Comment: @ElroyFlynn that's true, if you get it via the Request object you can POST it in whatever format you want provided you can decipher it the other end. If your Attribute based solution answers your original question you should create and accept an answer so others can see it if they come across this question.